# Fetch localized phone label using Contacts frameworks

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactstore, contacts-framework

I'm trying to fetch localized phone label value using CNContact.My attampt so far:

```
    NSError *error = nil;

    CNContactFetchRequest *fetchRequest =[[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];

    [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

       CNLabeledValue *phoneNumberValue = contact.phoneNumbers.firstObject;

       NSString *label = phoneNumberValue.label;
       NSLog(@"Phone Label: %@",label); //Logs value like _$!<Home>!$_

       CNPhoneNumber *phoneNumber = phoneNumberValue.value;
       NSString *phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.stringValue;

       NSLog(@"Phone No: %@",phoneNumberString);
    }];
```

The problem is the phone label returns raw value like `_$!<Home>!$_`, `_$!<Mobile>!$_`. But I need Plain text like **Home**, **Mobile**. Is there any way I can get the localized value using Contact frameworks. I don't want to use Addressbook as it is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `CNLabeledValue`s class method  `+ localizedStringForLabel:` and pass the label

example:

```
   CNLabeledValue *phoneNumberValue = contact.phoneNumbers.firstObject;
   NSString *label = phoneNumberValue.label;
   label = [CNLabeledValue localizedStringForLabel:label];
   NSLog(@"Phone Label: %@",label); //Logs value like home
```

Comment: Still getting `_$!<Home>!$_`

Comment: are the contacts from an exchange server by chance?

Comment: cause exchange doesn't really support custom labels... MIGHT be the issue then

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. this code works correctly.

Comment: Here's the updated `Swift 3` localized string without _$!<...>!$_:
phone number: `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>.localizedString(forLabel: label)`

email:
`CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: label)`

Comment: @Daij-Djan My email labels are also formatted with this prefix/suffix.  Perhaps they are added by syncing macOS and/or iOS Contacts with Google Contacts. 

The only exception is that email addresses labeled “Email” are NOT formatted with this prefix/suffix.

Answer (score 14):

And here it is in Swift 3:

```
let displayNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers.map() {
    let label = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: $0.label ?? "")
    return label + ": \u{200E}" + $0.value.stringValue
}
```

Added unicode LeftToRight override, to ensure the number is not reversed on RTL languages.

Answer (score 2):

add this line Contact Access

```
 if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey){

         for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                        let number  = phoneNumber.value

                        let number2 = number.stringValue

                        let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: phoneNumber.label! )

                        print("\(lable)  \(number.stringValue)")
                    }


                }
```